# RegEx pattern oversteps the target

Tags: c#, regex

I am working with a RegPattern to identify and capture URL's in a CSS file and appends a version identifier. This pattern works most of the time. However, one of the packaged CSS files is foiling it.

```
url\((\""|\')?(?<path>(.*))?(\""|\')?\)
```

When used with this chunk of CSS:

```
.ui-widget-overlay { background: #252526 url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_252526_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .50;filter:Alpha(Opacity=50); }
```

It captures this chunk of text:

```
url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_252526_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .50;filter:Alpha(Opacity=50)
```

This is being used in C# with a call to the Replace method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is **greedy** Regex. Since you have another bracket in your CSS, it makes `.*` as the whole strin.

Use this:

```
 url\((\""|\')?(?<path>([^\)]+))?(\""|\')?\)
```

I have replaced `.*` with `[^\)]+` (you can use `[^\)]*`  but I feel URL cannot be blank) => so it will find all characters that are not closin brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to make the `.*` non-greedy by adding `?` after the `.*`

Before:

```
url\((\""|\')?(?<path>(.*))?(\""|\')?\)
```

After:

```
url\((\""|\')?(?<path>(.*?))?(\""|\')?\)
```

Note that the simplest fix is not necessarily the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` bit is "greedy" - it'll match as much as it possibly can.  And because there's another right parenthesis later on in that line, that lets it count the first left parenthesis as part of the `.*` - which it's more than happy to do!

As long as none of your URLs have parentheses in them, changing `.*` to `[^)]*` (you might need to escape it - not sure) should take care of everything.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

> `url\([^)]+\)`

Answer (score 0):

The *immediate* problem is that you've got the second question mark in the wrong place.  The first part of `(?<path>(.*))?` matches zero or more of any characters and saves them in a group named "path", and the `?` makes the whole thing optional.  You probably meant to make the `.*` non-greedy, which you would do by moving the question mark inside the group: `(?<path>.*?)` (I also got rid of the unneeded inner group.)

But that still leaves you with a very brittle regex.  It doesn't account for optional whitespace surrounding the URL, and it can be fooled by quotes or parentheses in the URL, which are legal if they're escaped with backslashes.  You could probably with that for quite some time, but there are plenty of perfectly legal inputs that it won't match, and illegal inputs that it won't match.  The same is true of `(?<path>[^)]*)`, which others have suggested.

Here's a more robust regex:

```
Regex cssUrls = new Regex(@"(?i)
  url\(\s*
  (?>
    ([""'])(?<path>(?>(?:(?!\1).)*))\1
   |
    (?<path>(?>(?:[^()'""\s]+|\\.)*))
  )
  \s*\)
");
```

The first alternative matches a URL in quotes, ensuring that the opening and closing quotes are of the same type.  The second alternative matches a non-quoted URL, optionally containing escaped parentheses, quotes, or whitespace.